# How to set password expiration to infinite in shadow file?

Tags: linux, shadow

I was reading more about [how passwords are stored on linux](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lame/LAME/linux-admin-made-easy/shadow-file-formats.html)
and came across the number of days until password must be changed.
The article I was reading says

```
 The number of days after which password must be changed 
 (99999 indicates user can keep his or her password 
 unchanged for many, many years)]
```

[image]

The 99999 days is around 277 years. I was wondering if in the year 2250 there will be another y2k situation where people's *nix machines using shadow format will not be able to login. Is there a way to set this date to infinity. It seem like a really bad design decision...

Answer (score 1):

Yes that will be an issue for password age but don't worry there is going to be a bigger problem before. The year 2038 is going to be problem for unixtimestamp.

Time values that are calculated as a signed 32-bit integer starting from jan 1st 1970 will not be able to encode times after jan 19th 2038.

Comment: This has now been confirmed as fixed in the Linux 5.6 Kernel

Answer (score 1):

What is the problem?.

It is **not** a fixed date, it is a difference from the last change.
The 99999 days means about 273 years of continuous use **after** the last time the password was changed (or initially set).

The last time a password was changed is related to UNIX time. A [32 bit signed value of seconds](http://www.unixtimestamp.com/) from `January 1, 1970`. That is now the default counter for UNIX time. By that, the UNIX time will need to be changed before it overflows at (about) year 2038 (~ 19/Jan/2038). Since OpenBSD, NetBSD and the [x32 ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI) for Linux already use a 64 bit `time_t`, it seems reasonable to expect that by year 2038 [a signed 64 bit will be the default counter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem). That will allow to keep counting for about 292 giga additional years, or as explained in the NTP part:

> The 64 bit second value is enough to provide unambiguous time representation until the universe goes dim.

The "last time a password was changed" is just the UNIX time divided by 24 hours, 60 minutes and 60 seconds. Today, it will be:

```
$ echo $(( $(date +%s) / 24 / 60 / 60 ))
16837
```

That is a reduction of about 16 bits ( 2^16=65536 ) from the UNIX time.

In short, make your application able to use a 64 bit UNIX counter, and so:

```
  What is the problem?
```

Answer (score 0):

if you think that any operating system out there today, is going to be around in year 2250, without any major changes, alleviating potential problems, we have a much bigger issue in our hands than just a stupid password expiration problem. Look what computers came in the past 70 or so years since ENIAC was invented. 230+ years in the future is close to infinity in these terms.